# Error al intentar instalar colorize en ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, tensorflow, virtualenv

Estoy intentando instalar este programa en la terminal de ubuntu.

https://github.com/mlhubber/colorize

para ello ejecuté estas tres lineas de código:

```
pip3 install mlhub
ml install   colorize
ml configure colorize
```

y al ejecutar la última lindea me aparece este mensaje de error:

```
  *** The following required system packages are already installed:
    python3-numpy python3-pydot python3-matplotlib python3-opencv python3-graphviz python3-toolz

  *** Installing Python package tensorflow-cpu by pip into
    /root/.mlhub/colorize/.python

  Do you want to pip install tensorflow-cpu [Y/n]?
```

Y selecciono que sí

```
  Do you want to pip install tensorflow-cpu [Y/n]? Y

  mlhub: An error was encountered:

  Usage:
    pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
    pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
    pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
    pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
    pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

  no such option: --no-warn-script-location
```

Sin embargo cuando selecciono que no obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
  Do you want to pip install tensorflow-cpu [Y/n]? n

  *** Installing Python package keras>=2.4.3 by pip into
  /root/.mlhub/colorize/.python

  Do you want to pip install keras>=2.4.3 [Y/n]? n

  *** Downloading required files ...

      * https://github.com/foamliu/Simple-Colorization/releases/download/v1.0/model.06-2.5489.hdf5
  using cached copy found in /root/.mlhub/colorize/cache/models/model.06-2.5489.hdf5 ...

  To view the model's README:

    $ ml readme colorize
```

selecciono la foto que quiero darle color y obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
  (tensorflow) root@apl00028:/tmp# ml color colorize --interactive /mnt/c/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Downloads/Photo.jpeg Photo_color.jpeg
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "color.py", line 29, in <module>
from utils import get_predict_api, plot_bw_color_comparison
    File "/root/.mlhub/colorize/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema de instalación?
¿O como puedo instalar un programa parecido para colorear fotos?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Ubuntu tienes? Sospecho que la versión de pip que trae Ubuntu no es tan nueva y no tiene el flag `--no-warn-script-location`. pip solo a partir de la versión 10.0.0b1 lo trae, pero Ubuntu Xenial usa la 8.8.1 y Bionic la 9.0.1.

Comment: Hola braver, la versión de ubuntu que tengo es Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. Es el terminal de ubuntu instalado en windows. ¿Me recomiendas actualizarlo?¿Cómo?

Comment: No deberías actualizarlo globalmente (o sea, usando `sudo pip3 -U pip`) porque los paquetes de Ubuntu que dependen de él necesitan esa versión en específico. Lo que sí puedes hacer es un entorno virtual para cada "proyecto", ya que al crear uno se instala la versión más reciente de pip, y está aislada del sistema.

Comment: por qué no corres el programa en un notebook de Colab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He intentado simular este caso de la misma manera para que me termine arrojando el mismo error que tienes:

```
$ -> ml color colorize --interactive 
...
import tensorflow as tf
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

¿Qué rutas tienes establecidas para python3 y para pip? Ejecuta los siguientes comandos:

- python:

```
which python
/home/userTest/anaconda3/bin/python
```

- pip:

```
which pip
/home/userTest/anaconda3/bin/pip
$ -> which pip
/home/userTest/anaconda3/bin/pip
```

- python3:

```
which python3
/home/userTest/anaconda3/bin/python3
```

- pip3:

```
which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
$ -> type pip3
pip3 está asociado (/usr/bin/pip3)
```

¿Puede ser que tengas rutas distintas establecidas? Es lo más probable.

Esta es una de las razones para trabajar con entornos virtuales.  [Más sobre entornos virtuales en la documentación de Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/venv.html)

De hecho, en la guía de tensorflow.org, recomiendan usar entorno virtual "Se deben utilizar entornos virtuales de Python para aislar del sistema la instalación del paquete":

[Instalar tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

Podrías intentar crear un entorno virtual para este tipo de cosas y evitar problemas con paquetes, imports, ejecuciones y rutas asociadas.

1. **Remover todo lo que instalaste para ml** (mlhub, tensorflow, keras,
   etc. **Depende de a donde señale tu ruta**)
2. **Instalar virtualenv**:

```
$ -> /usr/bin/pip3 install -U virtualenv
```

3. **Crear entorno virtual**:

```
$ -> virtualenv --system-site-packages -p /usr/bin/python3 ./venv
```

4. **Activar el entorno virtual:**

```
$ -> source ./venv/bin/activate
```

De esta manera puedes instalar paquetes sin afectar al sistema. De hecho, si haces un `type pip3` puedes ver que cambia la ruta:

```
$ -> type pip3
pip3 is /home/userTest/venv/bin/pip3
```

5. **Actualizamos e instalamos mlhub y lo configuramos**:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ -> pip3 install mlhub
$ -> ml install colorize
$ -> ml configure colorize
```

Te pedirá de nuevo instalar tensorflow, keras, entre otros pero ya lo hará en el entorno virtual.

De hecho, podemos verlo listando el contenido en el entorno virtual:

```
$ -> ls -1 venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ | grep mlhub
mlhub
mlhub-3.7.2.dist-info
```

Ahora podemos hacer una prueba:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Adrián, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Me ha parecido muy útil la solución de crear un entorno virtual. Sin embargo cuando intento ejecutar el punto 3 tengo el siguiente output: FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/usr/bin/python3' -> '/root/venv/bin/python' Lo he obviado llegando hasta el final; llegando al punto 5 y ejecutar pip3 install mlhub y obtengo el siguiente output -bash: /root/venv/bin/pip3: /root/venv/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola, Adrián. Parece como si ya tuvieras el entorno virtual creado (.venv). Verifica si ya lo tienes y si puedes eliminarlo en caso de no necesitarlo. Mejor no avanzar hasta el resto de puntos hasta que el entorno virtual no esté correcto. Podrías crearlo con otro nombre o en otro directorio distinto a `/root` e incluso con un nuevo usuario que crees para dejarlo fuera de ámbito root. Me comentas si te ha servido, saludos.

Comment: Bien! funciona correctamente. Una última duda, entonces me recomiendas instalar a partir de ahora los programas activando el entorno source ./venv/bin/activate y después ejecutando el código de instalación pip3 install .... no? ¿Automáticamente cambia la ruta de instalación?

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado. Desde la propia documentación de Python recomiendan utilizar virtualenvs por cada proyecto que vayas a abordar [https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#:~:text=virtualenv%20is%20used%20to%20manage,can%20install%20virtualenv%20using%20pip.]. Al momento de que activas el entorno virtual, cambia por así decirlo el PATH asignado para pip, y los paquetes instalados estarán dentro del entorno virtual a utilizar.